# Concatenate File Url and Check for path Powershell error

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to get file path from the user and concatenating the file name and creating that file in the folder and then checking if the file exists. File is created and path looks correct to me but when I try to check if file path exists using test-path, it keeps failing that it does not exist

I can see the file and it exists in my system. When I copy the path and try to open in windows explorer, it gives me an error but when I try to right click on the file and copy the name and then check in windows explorer, it works. I am not sure if concatenation is adding some special characters.

```
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter file Name :'     #user entered Test123
$filePath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Path:'   #user entered C:\Documents

$File = ($filePath + "\" + $fileName + ".json")

 If (!(test-path $File)) {
    Write-Host "File does not exist"
    Exit 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to get path from user and concatenating the file name and creating that file in the folder and then checking if the file exists

Comment: The code shown does not create anything. It's also missing important parts such as where `$filepath` and `$filename` are created and how. You  should edit your post according to the stackoverflow guidelines. You are not new here so you should already know where to find these if you need a refresher. Lastly, save yourself trouble by using `Join-Path`

Comment: @DougMaurer Just did. Can you check now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concatenation is not valid.

Based on our exchange below, removed the original response, now that you've clarified your use case.

```
Clear-Host
$filePath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Path'
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter file Name'


# Debug - check variable content
($File = "$filePath\$fileName.json")

If (!(test-path $File)) 
{Write-Warning -Message 'File does not exist'}

# Results - Using a bad name
<#
Enter Path: D:\Temp
Enter file Name: NoFile
WARNING: File does not exist
#>

# Results - using a good file
<#
D:\temp\NewJsonFile.json
#>
```

Or

```
Clear-Host
$filePath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Path'
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter file Name'
Try 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$filePath\$fileName.json" -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Verbose 'Success' -Verbose
}
Catch 
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Error using $fileName"
    $PSitem.Exception.Message
}

# Results
<#
Enter Path: D:\temp
Enter file Name: BadFileName
WARNING: Error using BadFileName
Cannot find path 'D:\temp\BadFileName.json' because it does not exist.
#>

# Results
<#
Enter Path: D:\temp
Enter file Name: NewJsonFile

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         05-Oct-20     13:06              0 NewJsonFile.json                                                                                                               
VERBOSE: Success
#>
```

Comment: There is no https here. I am creating file using that concatenated file path in -outFile parameter and it creates the file correctly but now when I am trying to check if the file exists using the same filePath, it does not work and when I hover over the file path, it has correct url so I do not understand

Comment: Then why are you prompting for a URL? If just a UNC, then that should be your prompt. See my update for you.

Comment: I updated my question by asking for the filePath with an example of user giving it as C:\Documents

Comment: That does not change what I provided. the approach is the same.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to powershell, I do not understand what do you mean by erroraction and stop parameter. Can you please remove the url part and add more comments to make me understand

Comment: This is using error handling. If the file is not found, stop the processing and show an error message. [$PSItem.Exception.Message], otherwise, process as expected.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

If the directory doesn't exist, you'll need to create that as well.

```
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter file Name :'     #user entered Test123
$filePath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Path:'   #user entered C:\Documents

$File = (Join-Path $filePath "$fileName.json")

If (test-path $filePath)
{
    Write-Host Folder exists! -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
else
{
    Write-Host Folder does not exist! -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $result = New-Item $filePath -ItemType Directory

    if($result)
    {
        Write-Host Folder created successfully! -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}

If (test-path $File)
{
    Write-Host File exists! -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
else
{
    Write-Host File does not exist! -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $result = New-Item $file -ItemType File

    if($result)
    {
        Write-Host File created successfully! -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```